# Is user case generalization ok in Clean Architecture?

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

I'm starting my first application using clean Architecture and have come across a question. I have 2 user cases:

1 - Get All users

2 - Get All articles

As you can see I could write two use cases for these 2 actions but, Is it ok to generalize the "Get All X" use cases and just create a use case named for example GetAll that could receive the type of the object to return all its items?

These use cases are really simple because the only logic that contains is a call to the repository to get the needed data. But I think my question stands for more complex use cases.

Comment: If your use cases do not contain any logic except forwarding the request to a repository then rethink your code organization. First get your logic into the use cases. Then answering the question above becomes easier.

Comment: Even if you create BaseClass and extend it, it does not improve anything. If you don't extend it, but use same BaseClass for both cases, how would you inject total different Repositories ? I would prefer two different classes, while calling them, i know intention from name